# ¿Para que sirve sobrescribir el método __new__ en python?

Tags: python, poo, constructor

Tengo una duda sobre el método mágico `__new__`, cuando estuve buscando información sobre esto me encontré con que es similar al método `__init__`, ya que `__init__` inicializa los valores de un objeto pero `__new__` construye la instancia. Aparte leí que el método `__new__` puede retornar un valor, capacidad que no tiene `__init__` que no sea un `None`. Mi duda es, ¿Para que precisamente se utiliza el método `__new__`, que ventajas tiene en comparación con el método `__init__`?
Otro punto es ¿Por que `__new__` utiliza `cls` como referencia del objeto y no `self`?

Comment: Dado que las clases usan paréntesis para ser instanciadas, estas no invocan al método `__call__` como lo hacen las funciones, sino el `__new__`

Comment: También se me olvido decir que le puedes poner cualquier nombre, `self` no es una palabra ressevada, tampoco lo es `cls`, se utiliza ese nombre por simple estándar. Le puede poner `jose` e igual funciona

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, nunca lo probé con otro nombre, recién me entere que si se podía.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma general, en la mayoría de lenguajes orientados a objeto, la creación de un nuevo objeto tiene lugar en dos fases:

1. Se crea el objeto en sí, "vacío" por así decir.
2. Se inicializa el objeto asignándole valores a sus propiedades

El paso 1 suele ser automático y transparente para el programador. Es decir, el entorno de ejecución del lenguaje que sea se ocupa del detalle de crear el objeto (reservar memoria en el *heap*, asociar el código de los diferentes métodos con el objeto creado, etc.)

El paso 2 en cambio exige la colaboración del programador, quien debe escribir un método especial dentro del objeto llamado su *constructor*.

Personalmente encuentro la palabra *constructor* un poco equívoca, pues (al menos para mí) tiene connotaciones de "creación", pero en realidad el constructor no se ocupa de crear el objeto, sino sólo de asignar valores iniciales a sus atributos (quizás llamando al constructor de la clase base, en caso de herencia). A mi me gustaría más que ese método se llamara *inicializador* en lugar de *constructor*.

En el caso de Python ambas etapas están claramente separadas en dos métodos especiales (o *dunder*, por que tienen un *double underscore*). Son los siguientes:

1. `__new__()` Este es el método encargado de crear al objeto, pero no de asignarle valores iniciales. Debe retornar como resultado el objeto que ha creado. Recibe como parámetro la clase a la que se supone que debería pertenecer el objeto creado. Cabe esperar que el objeto que se crea y se retorna desde `__new__()` pertenecerá a esa clase también, pero realmente no es obligatorio (lo que puede llevar a cosas bien raras)
2. `__init__()` este es el método encargado de asignar valores iniciales al objeto creado desde `__new__()`. Como primer parámetro recibe el objeto en cuestión que debe ser inicializado (típicamente el parámetro a través del cual lo recibe se llama `self`).

No es muy habitual proporcionar tu propia implementación de `__new__()`. Al no hacerlo, tu clase heredará la implementación de `object.__new__()` que forma parte del lenguaje y que crea un objeto genérico, del tipo apropiado, y retorna ese objeto. Sí es habitual en cambio proporcionar tu implementación de `__init__()` para asignar valores iniciales a ese objeto creado.

Pero `__new__()` puede retornar algo que no sea una instancia de la clase correcta, por lo que en ese caso `__init__()` no llega a ser invocado. Podríamos decir entonces que los dos pasos antes mencionados serían algo equivalente a:

```
def crear_e_inicializar_objeto_de_la_clase_cls(cls, *args, **kwargs):
  # 1. Crearlo
  obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  if isinstance(obj,cls):
     # 2. Inicializarlo
     cls.__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  return obj
```

Y se usaría así:

```
class Ejemplo:
  def __init__(self, valor):
      self.valor = valor


ejemplo = crear_e_inicializar_objeto_de_la_clase_cls(Ejemplo, 4)
print(ejemplo.valor)
```

Solo que tal función no existe en realidad, pero es lo que se ejecuta cuando haces `ejemplo = Ejemplo(4)`

Observa que el parámetro que se le está pasando al `Ejemplo()` será el que se le pasará a `__init__()` una vez el objeto haya sido creado.

Si en cambio la clase `Ejemplo` implementara su propio `__new__()`, podríamos usarlo para añadirle algún tipo de *metainformación* que esté relacionada con su creación (por ejemplo la hora a la que fue creado):

```
import datetime

class Ejemplo:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      obj = super().__new__(cls)
      obj._created_at = datetime.datetime.now()
      return obj
    def __init__(self, valor):
      self.valor = valor

ejemplo = Ejemplo(4)
```

En este caso el objeto `ejemplo` tendría un atributo `ejemplo.valor` que fue asignado desde el constructor (`__init__`) y otro `ejemplo._created_at` que fue asignado en el momento de su creación desde `__new__()`. Observa cómo hemos usado `super()` para delegar la creación del objeto en sí a la clase base (es decir, en este caso al `__new__()` por defecto de los objetos Python, que es quien sabe cómo reservar la memoria, etc.)

Y un ejemplo mucho más raro, en el que `__new__()` no devuelve un objeto del tipo esperable:

```
import datetime

class Ejemplo:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      obj = "Hola"
      return obj
    def __init__(self, valor):
      self.valor = valor

ejemplo = Ejemplo(4)
```

Aquí `__new__()` está devolviendo una cadena. Por tanto la variable `ejemplo` será una cadena a todos los efectos. El resto de la clase `Ejemplo` no pinta nada (su método `__init__()` ni siquiera será invocado). Este ejemplo por tanto es bastante inútil, y sirve solo para demostrar que python te deja hacer cosas bien raras (que pueden ser útiles quizás en ciertos escenarios, especialmente si la clase que se está programando es una metaclase).

En cuanto a **¿Por que `__new__` utiliza `cls` como referencia del objeto y no `self`?**, `cls` no es la referencia al objeto, sino a la clase que se pretende instanciar. Por un lado está claro que `__new__()` no puede recibir una referencia al objeto, ya que éste aún no ha sido creado (y típicamente la palabra `self` se usa para referirse al objeto sobre el que se va a actuar). Cabe preguntarse sin embargo por qué se le pasa como parámetro `cls`, que es la clase del objeto que se quiere crear. La razón se hace más clara al ver el ejemplo que puse antes en el que, desde dentro de `__new__()` se creaba una instancia usando `super().__new__(cls)`. Aquí vemos que la clase que hemos recibido como parámetro se la pasamos a su vez al `__new__()` de la clase base. Eventualmente esto acabará invocando `object.__new__()` que es la parte de Python que sabe cómo crear objetos, y ese método debe recibir como parámetro cuál es la clase a instanciar, cosa que probablemente usará para inicializar los atributos de clase, el MRO, y otros detalles que dependan de la clase en sí, y no de la instancia.

Comment: Falto explicar la última parte de la pregunta:  *¿Por que `__new__` utiliza `cls` como referencia del objeto y no `self`?* que ya lo dije en un comentario

Comment: @Christian Tienes razón. Ya lo he ampliado. Gracias por señalarlo

Comment: Hay que aclarar que si se trata de una jerarquía de clases, se invoca primero el método de la clase padre y así hasta llegar a la de `object.__new__()`. Por otro lado, si tu clase deriva de un _tipo invariante_ como `tuple` o `str`, no se puede alterar la instancia desde el `__init__`, pero sí que es posible desde el `__new__` antes de crear la instancia invocando el método `super().__new__`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por responder, ya me quedo en claro que `cls` hacia referencia a la clase y no al objeto, sino que cuando hice uso de `self` las primeras veces que implementaba POO en python nunca le di relevancia a su origen pero ahora se que eso se encargaba el método `__new__`. Tengo una duda @abulafia cuando mencionaste los atributos de la clase en el ultimo párrafo, ¿Aparte también estas son las que van ubicadas al principio de la clase respecto a su sintaxis, fuera del método `__init__` e incluso del método `__new__`, o no tienen que ver nada?

Comment: @Luis_LATAM019 Sí, los atributos de clase son los que se inicializanen el cuerpo de la clase, fuera de cualquier otro método de la misma. Esos atributos son compartidos (para lectura) por todas las instancias de esa clase. También son accesibles usando la sintaxis `Clase.atributo`